# How to check if 2 `XSSFSheet` are identical without having to loop over every cell in each sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

The goal is to check if 2 sheets are identical or not in Java by using the Apache POI maven library

So let's say we have the following method :

```java
boolean isIdentical(final XSSFSheet firstSheet, final XSSFSheet secondSheet);
```

I know this can be done by looping every row and every cell and then checking if the cell value is the same, like the following

```java
    public boolean isIdentical(final XSSFSheet firstSheet, final XSSFSheet secondSheet) {  
        for (int rowIndex = firstSheet.getFirstRowNum(); rowIndex <= firstSheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
            final XSSFRow row1 = firstSheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            final XSSFRow row2 = secondSheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            for (int cellIndex = row1.getFirstCellNum(); cellIndex <= row2row1getLastCellNum(); cellIndex++) {
                final XSSFCell cell1 = row1.getCell(cellIndex);
                final XSSFCell cell2 = row2.getCell(cellIndex);
                // check if cell has same raw value 
                // ...
            }
        }
```

But does anyone know if there is a way to compare the data in a more efficient way, rather then going through each cell in the sheet ?

Thank you!

Comment: Define "identically". The sheets are "identical" if all of the cell values are the same? What about row heights, column widths, cell styles, data formats, drawings, ...? If your definition of "identical" really is: contains the same raw data, then your method will be good if corrected [You often mess up the two sheet's rows and cells in your code.]. How else should that be checked as by comparing the stored data?

Comment: @Axel Richter By identical I mean the 2 sheets should contains the same raw data .Do you think there is a more efficient way to do that without having to loop through all the cells ?

Comment: No. If the requirement is to compare the data, then there is no more efficient way than to compare the data. At least I can't think of any.

Comment: Depending on context, you might check the exit status of `cmp` before resorting to the cell-by-cell approach.